# How do I combine two dataframes vertically, but only keep the columns that are matching?

Tags: r, rbind, data-wrangling

I am hoping to combine two dataframes vertically that have only some columns that are common. However, I want to drop any columns that are not available in both dataframes. When I use bind_rows() it keeps all columns and fills non-matching rows with NA. And I can't use rbind()  because that requires the same columns.

What is a good solution here?

Comment: Use `intersect` between the colnames of two `dataframes` and drop the remaining and use `rbind`

Comment: Something like `Common <- intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))
df3 <- rbind(df1[,Common], df2[, Common])`

Answer (score 2):

You can intersect the column names and select only those names:

```r
df1 <- tibble(a = runif(100), b = runif(100), c = runif(100))
df2 <- tibble(a = runif(100), d = runif(100))

commcols <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
newdf <- bind_rows(
    select(df1, all_of(commcols)),
    select(df2, all_of(commcols))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove columns with NAs afterwards, you can use:

```
df[ , apply(df, 2, function(x) !any(is.na(x)))]
```

Another option is to identify columns that are in common before joining, and then just join those:

```
myvars1<- names(df1) %in% names(df2)
myvars2<- names(df2) %in% names(df1)
dplyr::bind_rows(df1[myvars1],df2[myvars2])
```